# RubyOnRails - selectbox not reload jquery mobile style after ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I have two select box in a html page, after the change of value on the first select, the values of the second box are updated. It work but the jquery mobile style of the second select box doesn't reload.

This is the html code:

```
   <select id="report_cod_resource_id" name="report[cod_resource_id]" data-theme="c" onchange="changeValue(this)">
     <%= Resource.find(:all).each do |r| %>
        <option value="<%= r.cod_resource %>">
          <%= r.description_resource %>
        </option>
    <% end %>
   </select>

  <!-- Home -->
  <div id="damage_list" Blockquote
    <select id="report_cod_damage_type_id" name="report[cod_damage_type_id]" data-theme="c" style="width:100%;">
      <%=
          if params[:resource_id]
            @resid=params[:resource_id];
          else
            @resid=1
          end
      %>
       <%= Damage.find_all_by_cod_resource_id(@resid).each do |r| %>

          <option value="<%= r.cod_damage %>">
            <%= r.description_damage %>
          </option>
      <% end %>
    </select>
  </div>
```

and this is ajax call:

> ```
> function changeValue(obj){
>           resource_id = $("#report_cod_resource_id").val();
>           $.ajax({
>               type: "GET",
>               url: "/reports/new",
>               data: "resource_id="+resource_id,
>               success: function(html){
>                   var part= $("<div/>").append(html).find('#damage_list').html();
>                   $("#damage_list").html(part);
>               }
>           });
>    }
> ```

**UPDATE I:**

I Edit my js code in this mode:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#report_cod_resource_id").bind( "change",function(event, ui) {
          var part;
          resource_id = $("#report_cod_resource_id").val();
          $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "/reports/new",
              data: "resource_id="+resource_id,
              success: function(html){
                  part= $("<select/>").append(html).find('#report_cod_damage_type_id').html();
                  $("#report_cod_damage_type_id").empty().append(part);
              }
          });
          $("#report_cod_damage_type_id").selectmenu('refresh');
      });
  });
```

now, the jquery mobile style isn't lost, the option values are updated but in the select menu remains the text of the old selected option although it isn't present in the option list.

**UPDATE II:**

Now, it works !!! I edit my code in this way:

```
   function changeValue(){
              var part;
              resource_id = $("#report_cod_resource_id").val();
              $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "/reports/new",
                  data: "resource_id="+resource_id,
                  success: function(html){
                      part= $("<select/>").append(html).find('#report_cod_damage_type_id').html();
                      $("#report_cod_damage_type_id").empty().append(part);
                      $("#damage_list").find('.ui-btn-text').text($("#report_cod_damage_type_id option:selected").text());
                  }
              });
      }
```

I  only added the 'option' tags, and so the style isn't lost.
In this mode are reloaded the new options but the old selected text of the 'select box' isn't changed!!! so i changed the text of the 'select box' with this code string:

```
$("#damage_list").find('.ui-btn-text').text($("#report_cod_damage_type_id option:selected").text());
```

Comment: Use `$( "#damage_list" ).selectmenu( "refresh" );` after you finish appending new selectmenu.

Comment: I try it but doesn't work

Comment: Add your solution as an answer. good luck!